# Styling a hr for internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Hey, in my quest to create as image light a site as possible, I'm looking to create two tone hr's.

I've achieved this in modern browsers, but want to achieve the same effect in ie6 and 7.

The current code I am using is

```
hr {
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF; 
    border-top:1px solid #dcdcdc; 
    clear:both; 
    height:0; 
    border-left:0px; 
    border-right:0px;
}
```

I've tried, with no success to make this work in ie6 and 7 without having to target the browsers specifically. Any thoughts?

(Heres my current project where I am employing this code, and looking to make it cross browser - http://www.qwibbledesigns.co.uk/preview/aurelius/ )

Cheers

Matt

Comment: Off topic - it looks like most of the site is placeholder, but you might want to note that "professional" is misspelled.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something like the following instead (and replace the `<hr>` with a `<div>`)

```
div {
    /* no need for border-left/right with the following: */
    border: none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF; 
    border-top:1px solid #dcdcdc; 
    clear:both; 
    height:0; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

(and don't forget to add an id or class to prevent all divs to look odd)

NOTE: this works on IE7, IE8 and on compliant browsers. Probably needs more tweaking for the 10 year old IE6, or even needs an image-hack (as so often).

Comment: That's worked in ie7, but in ie6, when I place the margin-bottom:20px; that I want on all <hr />'s, it add's the padding, but also puts space between the two borders. I tried setting line-height:0 which didnt work. I set font-size:0; and achieved making the gap between the borders much smaller, but still no cigar.

You can view the results here; www.qwibbledesigns.co.uk/preview/aurelius/index.html

Any thoughts?

Comment: getting things to work in IE6 requires a different ballgame (and a lot of frustration and time, which is why so many companies leave IE6 alone). Consider fixing it programmatically (i.e. with a JS onload). Also: make sure there's some content, like `&nbsp;` in the `div`. If nothing works, use the trick that they used 10 years ago when IE6 was born: make an image, stretch it. That's one method that always works.

Comment: Beautiful, '&nbsp;' did the trick, a big thanks to you man.

I started coding long after IE6, so am not as well read up on these kind of tricks =)

Comment: Unfortunately, this method loses all semantic meaning of the HR. And users wanting to style the HR in a CMS text editor for end users will be sad.

Answer (score 21):

I havent seen any good answer for this but though my own work figured out the following code should work for styling a HR to look consistent in firefox, safari, chrome and IE (not sure if it works below IE7).

```
hr {
    color:#bfbfbf; /*used for IE, top color*/
    background:#bfbfbf; /*firefox and chrome, top color*/
    min-height: 0px;  /*required to get IE to render the top pixel color*/
    border-left: 0px; 
    border-right: 0px; 
    border-top: 1px solid #bfbfbf; /*Your top color*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff; /*Your bottom color*/
}
```

Comment: This should have more votes. It is actually about how to style the <hr>, getting around IE idiocy. For me the color declaration to deal with weird side borders when there is height was the secret.

Answer (score 4):

If you're clients have already plastered the site with < hr > tags you can just style hr as well as the hr class then swap < hr > tags out for  in ie6 and ie7.

Use the css posted by Abel:

```
hr, .hr {
    /* no need for border-left/right with the following: */
    border: none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF; 
    border-top:1px solid #dcdcdc; 
    clear:both; 
    height:0; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then in your js file just put:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) <= 7) {
    $("hr").replaceWith('<div class="hr"></div>');
}
```

obviously jQuery is required for this fix, but it worked well for me.

Comment: There are so many problems with this, especially if you have any sort of Javascript DOM generation in your web application. Matt's pure CSS solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the easiest way is to use `<div class="hr"></div>` instead. Styling `<hr/>` cross-browser is head-breaking, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

```
hr 
{ 
  /* hr css reset */
  color: white; /* if parent element's background is white - old ie versions fix */ 
  border: 0; 
  background: transparent; 
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /* hr css reset end */
  /* custom styles */
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting height to 2px solved the issue for me.

```
hr {
    margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
}
```