# <hr> different in internet explorer and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm having a problem with the height of hr. It's okay now in google chrome but hr is too high for IE.

CSS:

```
hr {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

Does anyone know how to change it so it works properly in IE? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: i see no difference in IE11 w7 or w8.1, can you precise wich IE you talk about ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017227/styling-a-hr-for-internet-explorer.  Basic answer: you can't rely on any "help" from the browser when styling hr tags for HTML5.

Comment: That's strange because I'm also using IE11.

Comment: Hmm okay, well thanks!

Comment: Are you using quirks mode, or compatibility mode with older versions?

Comment: I am just using the standards mode